# Swapping CAPSLOCK and ESC keys, but "deeper"

Tags: keyboard-layout

I'm on Manjaro with `bspwm` and `sxhkd` (if that matters).

Currently, I have `setxkbmap -option caps:swapescape` in my `.xinitrc` which works to swap my <kbd>ESC</kbd> and <kbd>CAPSLOCK</kbd> keys. However, the swap doesn't seem to work with all applications. In some apps, mainly Virtualbox VMs and games, the 2 keys are swapped for the host but not the VM/app, which makes using them confusing and annoying.

Is there a way to make the swap "deeper", such that it works with every subsequent application?

Comment: GUI games launched by Steam. I don't game much but Virtualbox VMs are certainly a problem.